# Disadvantages of Sequel gem

Tags: ruby, orm, sinatra, sequel

Are there any alternatives to the Sequel ORM when working on a Sinatra-based app?

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: You ask for disadvantages in the title, but alternatives in the question. Which do you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, you are not forced to use Sequel with Sinatra. If you wish you can use Datamapper or an other ORM.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to use Sequel with Sinatra. Sinatra is pretty agnostic.

If you are interested in using ActiveRecord its pretty straightforward:
    require 'rubygems'
    require 'sinatra'
    require 'active_record'

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  :adapter => 'sqlite3',
  :database =>  'sinatra_application.sqlite3.db'
)
```

You can read more about ActiveRecord and Sinatra [here](http://recipes.sinatrarb.com/p/models/active_record). There is also a gem [sinatra-activerecord](https://github.com/janko-m/sinatra-activerecord) that handles some of the boilerplate.

There is also the Ruby Object Mapper (rom-rb) which is a pretty nice implementation of the DataMapper pattern if you want something more fully featured than Sequel, but aren't interested in using ActiveRecord.

Answer (score 1):

You might check out [Padrino](http://www.padrinorb.com/). It's a lightweight framework with a Sinatra core that supports several ORMs right out of the box.

Comment: Indeed, Padrino is very modular so you can just include the ORM parts without any of the other functionality. Padrino supports the following as ORM by default: mongoid, activerecord, datamapper, couchrest, mongomatic, ohm, ripple, sequel

Answer (score 0):

You can use DataMapper or ActiveRecord, or just plain DBI. Sinatra does not have any integrated support for a specific ORM framework.